# Can UFW work with iptables-persistent?

Tags: iptables, ufw, iptables-persistent

I used a script to set up `iptables` rules and then made them persistent with `iptables-persistant`. This is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37412/how-can-i-ensure-transmission-traffic-uses-a-vpn) as a means to prevent a certain user sending traffic over `eth0` so it can just use `tun0` aka a `VPN`.

But I also use `ufw` to easily manage firewall rules.

Now, if I make the rules persistant `ufw` seems not beeing able to load its own rules on top of that.

Is this a basic conflic? Or should I be able to solve it?

Of course I could make the rules persistant after I added `sudo ufw enable` but then any changes to `ufw` afterwards would have to be persistet, too. This is something I want to avoid because it might be a cause for errors.

Comment: I put an nft script in  `/etc/nft.d/` and got no conflicts. I use `nft` as it is newer and easier to use.

Comment: > Now, if I make the rules persistant ufw seems not beeing able to load its own rules on top of that. @Ben what sort of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ufw` is compatible with `netfilter-persistent`. It's loaded separately. You can tell by listing the systemd unit files:

```
% systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | egrep "netfilter-persistent|ufw"
netfilter-persistent.service          enabled
ufw.service                           enabled
```

That said, it's harder to manage firewall rules with two tools instead of just one. UFW is mostly isolated from other IPtables rules, but it is possible to accidentally add a rule via the `iptables` command that interferes with `ufw` rules and visa versa.